# Why Decryption function Change all values to Null?

Tags: mysql, encryption

I am trying to encrypt all Company data. But I will see only Null Values when I want to decrypt them. I checked my data after encryption and It looks encrypted.

Here is my code

```
update TCB set Company=aes_encrypt(Company,'1234') WHERE Company= CONVERT(Company USING ASCII);
//I added where clause in case if there is any Encrypted data

select *,cast(aes_decrypt(Company,'1234') as char(100))  from TCB;
```

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AES_ENCRYPT()` returns binary bytes, not text. When you saved the encrypted data to the same column, which I assume is a varchar or text column with a character set, it tried to interpret the binary bytes as encodings in the column's character set. It's likely that many of the bytes weren't valid encodings for that character set, so you ended up with garbage data that cannot be decrypted.

```
mysql> create table tcb ( company text );

mysql> insert into tcb set company = 'company';

mysql> update tcb set company = aes_encrypt(company, '1234');
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 1

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                                          |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect string value: '\x8F\x94O\x1D\xB9\x07...' for column 'company' at row 1 |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You should save encrypted data to a VARBINARY or BLOB column. These data types don't have a character set, they just store binary bytes.

```
mysql> create table tcb (company text, company_enc blob);

mysql> insert into tcb set company = 'company';

mysql> update tcb set 
    company_enc = aes_encrypt(company, '1234'),
    company = NULL; /* no more plain text copy */

mysql> select aes_decrypt(company_enc, '1234') from tcb;
+----------------------------------+
| aes_decrypt(company_enc, '1234') |
+----------------------------------+
| company                          |
+----------------------------------+
```

Another solution is to store encrypted data after converting the binary bytes to a printable string of hex digits.

```
mysql> update tcb set company = 'company';

mysql> update tcb set company = hex(aes_encrypt(company, '1234'));

mysql> select company from tcb;
+----------------------------------+
| company                          |
+----------------------------------+
| 8F944F1DB907685B94F8F21554E57396 |
+----------------------------------+

mysql> select aes_decrypt(unhex(company), '1234') from tcb;
+-------------------------------------+
| aes_decrypt(unhex(company), '1234') |
+-------------------------------------+
| company                             |
+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Bill Karwin, Thank you

Comment: Do you know any way to prevent updating if the key password is incorrect?

Comment: How would `AES_ENCRYPT()` know if the key password is incorrect? When you're encrypting, any key is correct. It's when you're *decrypting* that you need to make sure to use the same key that you used when you encrypted.

Comment: Ok, Great, And the last question is about hex, So this encryption may happen several times and I do not want to encrypt one file several times, I used WHERE Company= CONVERT(Company USING ASCII); to make sure if the data is not encrypted yet. But Now I used Hex and not sure how to check it again. do you have any recommendation?

Comment: I recommend to use two columns. One VARCHAR to store an unencrypted clear string, and the other a VARBINARY, in which you only store encrypted data. See my second example above. When you encrypt, assign NULL to the clear text column. Then you know which ones have been encrypted.

Comment: I saw that but I have to encrypt data and I do not want to have another copy that is not encrypted. So the second example does not work and I used REGEXP '^[0-9ABCDEF]+$')=1 to make sure if they are Hex or Not but still some company names are like AAA or ABB so this method does not work. I used varchar in this example and it worked "update usersExample3 set password=aes_encrypt(password,'1234')" and password is varchar

Comment: That's why you should assign NULL to the plain text column as you encrypt it, storing the encrypted version in a second column. Then you don't have two copies. I'll edit my example above to show this.

Comment: Oh Thank You So much, I will look at it

Comment: It's an important part of relational database theory that each column should be used for only one type of data. Don't store both encrypted and unencrypted data in the same column. It just leads to confusing situations like the one you're in. If you find yourself struggling to make a regular expression to match encrypted strings while not matching unencrypted strings (what if my plain text is a string of hex digits?), then you have an ambiguous problem. Using different columns for different types of data resolves the ambiguity.

Comment: Really Appreicate for answers